# How to setup Arrivals Thread Group(Custom Thread Groups)

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am new to Jmeter I don't have any idea about it. I want to use a Jmeter plugin named as **Custom Thread Group -> Arrivals Thread Group** available at location https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ArrivalsThreadGroup/ for arrival rate simulation. I searched a lot about these properties but didn't get clear definition or understanding. I have a vague idea about its configuration properties. I wrote the details I know about all these properties as a code comment

```
Target Rate(arrivals/min): 60
Ramp Up Time(min): 1  // how long to take to "ramp-up" to the full number of threads 
Ramp-Up Steps Count: 10 // It divides Ramp-up time into specified parts and ramp-up threads accordingly 
Hold Target Rate Time(min): 2// It will repeat the same for the next two minutes
Thread Iterations Limit:
```

Can anybody help me to understand clearly what is the significance of all these properties?

[image]

Comment: **Hold Target Rate Time(min)** wont repeat ramp up, it will keep the threads in steady state for the duration specified. In your case it will keep number of threads 60 for the end of the run.

Comment: steady state means?

Comment: It is the duration where the number of threads is steady. In your example above, from 00:00:54 - 00:03:00 is the steady state, where the number of threads reached the number you want and its not changing anymore till the end of the test

Answer (score 0):

**According to above settings:**

**Target Rate**: 60 arrivals in a minute means there will be one arrival per second. Each second JMeter will kick off a virtual user which will be executing samplers.

**Ramp-up time:** the time which will be taken to reach the target rate, i.e. JMeter starts from zero arrivals per minute and increases the arrivals rate to 60 arrivals per minute in 60 seconds.

**Ramp-up steps:** here you can set the “granularity” of increasing arrivals rate, more steps - more smooth pattern, fewer steps - you will have “spikes”

**Hold Target Rate:**  it will keep the threads in steady state for the duration specified. In your case, it will keep a number of threads 60 for the end of the run. As explained in above comment.

So according to settings, JMeter will ramp-up from 0 to 1 arrival per second in one minute plus run the test for 2 minutes.

If I have 1 sampler in Test Plan it will be something like 153 executions, if I have 2 samplers - 153 executions per sampler, in total 306 executions. Approximate request rate will be 50 requests/minute.